# Appreciate figure to Fig. and table to Tab. with \usepackage{caption}

Tags: tables, floats

I did some modifications on captions using the `\usepackage{caption}`. Tho I can't figure out how to modify figure to Fig. and table to Tab.. The way I did it, both are change to Fig..

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}

% LaTeX colores: https://latexcolor.com
\definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}

% Caption
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-parens}{\textcolor{darkcerulean}{\textbf{Fig. #2: }}}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,font={small},labelformat=bf-parens,labelsep=none,format=plain]{caption} % https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[draft]{altvenative_07}
\caption{Test figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|cc}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test table caption.}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: Please make your code _minimal_. The whole colour/header stuff is completely irrelevant to the question. In order to show the effect you can use an empty `table*` environment with the `\caption` macro in it, there is no need to fill it with an actual large table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines in your code

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-parens}{\textcolor{darkcerulean}{\textbf{Fig. #2: }}}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,font={small},labelformat=bf-parens,labelsep=none,format=plain]{caption}
```

should be replaced with

```
\DeclareCaptionFont{darkcerulean}{\color{darkcerulean}}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,font={small},labelfont={darkcerulean,bf},labelsep=colon,format=plain]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tab.}
```

See sections 2.8 and 4.1 of the [Caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I read that part and understood that I only can use it inside the `table` or `figure` environment, but was searching for something that could be inserted into the preamble so it affects the document globally, but apparently this works. Thanks for your help!